# Why does my Bind RPZ config work for one host, but not the other (SERVFAIL)

Tags: linux, bind, dns-zone, rpz

I have some hosts in a DMZ which need to use LDAP resources on the LAN. We don't forward DNS into the LAN, so instead of adding entries in individual `/etc/hosts`, I decided to try a Bind RPZ zone to handle DNS to keep all the workarounds in one place.

It seems to work for one host `oldserver.internal.org` but not the other `ldap.mydom.com`. I should mention that `ldap.mydom.com` returns an internet routable address from `8.8.8.8` (however, not usable for LDAP).

Why do I get SERVFAIL when querying `ldap.mydom.com` ?

```
# nslookup ldap.mydom.com 192.168.1.4
Server:         192.168.1.4
Address:        192.168.1.4#53

** server can't find ldap.mydom.com: SERVFAIL


####### bind server #########

# /etc/bind/named.conf.options

...
   response-policy {
               zone "rpz";
   };
...


# /etc/bind/named.conf.local
...
      zone "rpz" in {
               type master;
               file "internal.rpz_zone.rpz";
      };
...
      zone "rpz" in {
               type master;
               file "external.rpz_zone.rpz";
      };
...



# /var/cache/bind/internal.rpz_zone.rpz
$TTL    300

@       IN SOA  myns1.mydom.com. (
            postmaster.mydom.com
            2016100805  ; serial
            1h          ; refresh
            15m         ; retry
            1w          ; expiry
            1h )        ; minimum

            IN NS myns1.mydom.com.
            IN NS myns2.mydom.com.


; we want internal DNS for this host
ldap.mydom.com            A        192.168.17.53
oldserver.internal.org    A        192.168.18.85

# /var/log/named.log
08-Oct-2018 09:52:18.550 queries: client 192.168.1.21#54254 (ldap.mydom.com): view internal: query: ldap.mydom.com IN A + (192.168.1.4)
```

Comment: When you get a SERVFAIL you often can see more details in the system log or something about the error.

Comment: All syslog shows is this (what looks related anyway). Is bind issuing SERVFAIL because egress is blocked?: 
`Oct  8 09:51:31 myns1 named[24905]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'ldap.mydom.com/A/IN': 200.200.200.100#53`